# Facebook needs to scrape twice to get the correct OpenGraph image

Tags: facebook, blogger, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a problem with OG tags and Facebook. Earlier this year, I installed Twitter Cards on my blog (http://nickalive.blogspot.com/; code below), and until recently, they've worked well with Facebook.

However, for the past couple of weeks, I'm finding that I have to submit posts twice on Facebook for the correct og:image to appear. The first time, the 'catch all' image appears, but when I get Facebook to rescrape it by resubmitting the post, the correct image appears.

If there a way to fix this?

Thanks. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add images sizes too, if you want to make sure Facebook can scrape it immediately. The tags are called `og:image:width` and `og:image:height`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#media

> Specify height and width for your image to ensure that the image loads
>   properly the first time it's shared.

Comment: I've added the tags to a test blog, but I'm still having to get Facebook to double scrape the posts. The tags I'm using are: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GoPZ1meTZto/XAQ83wluMDI/AAAAAAABBx0/ITJcCY0tOCoJzSgjlIMIJKflsvTAbTJ6wCLcBGAs/s1600/ogtags2.png

Comment: was that test page scraped before? is it public? this works for all my pages since many years.

Comment: Yep, it's public and has been scraped in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `og:image` tag from twitter cards code because Blogger automatically adds one.

Comment: I've removed the tag, and it seems to have worked, however, a preview image doesn't load when composing a post on Facebook, and only shows up once the post is published. The reason I included the og:tag is that when a direct link to my homepage is posted on Twitter, generic image is displayed. Is there a way to have my logo displayed when a link to the homepage is tweeted?

Comment: To use a tag only on homepage put it between this conditional tag `<b:if cond='data:view.isHomepage'> your code here </b:if>`

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others with the same issue.

Comment: I've tried adding it to a test template (http://nickoozenews.blogspot.com/), however, it's thrown up some strange results: On Twitter, the generic grey logo loaded, and on Facebook, a completely random image was used.

Comment: Update: I've added this code, which works on Twitter, however, still makes a random image load when a link to the homepage is posted on Facebook. Also, is the code acceptable, or will it cause errors having two similar tags?: https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BKYXB-XHLNQ/XAcYkjQ7wYI/AAAAAAABB4c/PTJ9t3pGRrYBIoEDsPbe2WYKVbWZ2YvZgCLcBGAs/s1600/ogtags3.png

Comment: I think you need to use all the most basic meta tags like og:title and og:url on homepage to prevent facebook from taking a random content [A guide here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/) and the two tags aren't similar, one for facebook and another for twitter.